# WhatsApp Chat Transfer from Google Drive to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, android, whatsapp.app, google-apps

My wife just got a brand new iPhone. I am just wondering, how do I transfer WhatsApp chat history from Google Drive to iCloud or directly to the iPhone. I have backed up everything to Google Drive. Just need to know how to get it on to the iPhone. I googled a bit and there are some tools out there. But all of them are Mac or Windows software. All my laptops at home are Linux (Ubuntu, Arch, Suse and Mint).

Comment: What do the help pages of WhatsApp say about chat migration?

Comment: @nohillside There is absolutely no information on this. I searched a lot through their FAQ pages, but couldn't find any info. I just am curious, I shouldn't be the only one going through this!

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/account-and-profile/about-changing-phones/, "Move to a different type of phone [...] You can’t transfer your chat history"

Comment: Yeah. I emailed them and got the same reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official and supported way of migrating WhatsApp chat history from an Android phone to an iPhone:

1. Read the [How to migrate your WhatsApp data from Android to iPhone](https://faq.whatsapp.com/686469079565350) page from the WhatsApp Help Center.
2. On this date (2023-01-10), as per the manual, the iPhone needs to be reset to its factory state: *"Your iPhone must be factory new or reset to factory settings to pair with the Move to iOS app and move data from your Android phone"*.

If you think the effort of resetting and reconfiguring the iPhone is worth migrating your chat history, this is the best option.

Here's a screenshot of WhatsApp in the iPhone right after restoring WhatsApp history during its initial setup:

[image: screenshot of iOS application with the text "Moving Chats from Android" and a progress bar for the migration process]